# Why am I getting this annoying log messages.CRON[17405]: (root) CMD every minute

Tags: security, cron, log, rsyslog

I have configured `rsyslog.conf` file to store log messages to mysql but I am getting some annoying log message in my MySql table. which looks like this.

```
Nov  3 14:48:01 username CRON[17405]: (root) CMD (location of my app >/dev/null 2>&1)
Nov  3 14:48:01 username CRON[17406]: (root) CMD (application name and loc >/dev/null 2>&1)
Nov  3 14:48:01 username CRON[17407]: (root) CMD (appname/location >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

The applications that are generating logs are the programs which I have created and are running as Daemon process.

Why am I getting these logs?
What should I write in rsyslog.conf to not store these type of logs in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because cron daemon's activity goes to system logs. It is not annoying in my opinion, rather life saving if - let's say - you have to know if crontab is executed or not. Beside that you can control the output by editing the `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file to this:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none,mail.none,cron.none -/var/log/syslog
```

The relevant part is the `cron.none` directive.